# Is there a replacement for the removed "Windows System Resource Manager" feature in the Windows Server 2012 R2 release?

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2012-r2, windows

Windows System Resource Manager (WSRM) [has been removed in Windows Server 2012 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303411.aspx), and I need a replacement.

I'm running a small RDP server on 2012 R2 Standard.  It only has 8 GB of RAM and I need a way to limit resources for each regular user so the system doesn't grind to a halt if a single user takes more than his fair share (for whatever reason).

I can easily use Server 2012 (*first "edition"*) instead, which [only has WSRM `deprecated`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh831568.aspx) instead of `removed`, as it isn't essential for me to use *R2*.

Is there any simple way to manage resources (mainly RAM) in Windows Server 2012 **R2** since the WSRM has been removed?

Comment: Microsoft [says](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831568.aspx): "Windows System Resource Manager (WSRM) is deprecated. Similar functionality is provided by Hyper-V."  Uhh, I don't think so?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think what Microsoft is saying there is that if you need resource isolation in Remote Desktop Services, you should use Remote Desktop Services Desktop Pools (VDI). WSRM was a poor-man's way of resource separation. That said, VDI is way more complicated with way more moving parts, so that's a definite punch in the gut for some people.

Comment: No, vdi is not the solution for wsrm hyper-v is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we're left with "Fair Share" resource sharing, enabled by default for Remote Desktop Services in 2012+, for CPU, Network, and Disk I/O. But not memory. So no, no memory balancing like we had with WSRM. Why did they specifically leave memory out of the FairShare policies?  I don't know.

You can implement fair sharing of memory across virtual machines on a Hyper-V hypervisor, but that is not the same thing as a Remote Desktop Session Host. So as of this moment I would say that they've taken that very particular functionality away and left us with no alternatives. I suspect (*this is conjecture*) that is what Microsoft meant when they stated "Similar functionality is provided by Hyper-V."  That it was sort of a naïve idea that "well, since the whole world is moving to VDI anyway, just use Hyper-V to balance memory across VMs." But again, I am ready and willing to be proven wrong.

Comment: So it appears there isn't an alternative, so I'll just use the first release of 2012.  It's frustrating, because I need a basic RDP setup in a VM for a university project I'm working on, and I don't want, nor can I, set up an entire virtual environment with a bunch of machines with different roles or use more than my limited ram. Grrrrr.

Comment: If you have to balance memory in windows you likely have a poorly written app that would perform better isolated.

Answer (score 4):

You can setup `Windows System Resource Manager` on *Windows Server 2012 **R2***. Even if it was removed by Microsoft, you **can manually install it** and use it.

I have listed the instructions here on my blog:
http://blog.iftvio.ro/index.php/windows-system-resource-manager-and-windows-server-2012-r2/

Related: [My post in a the Microsoft forums thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6d1ae954-a481-4ebd-883c-a5f0d9be7d62/windows-server-resource-manager-deprecated?forum=winserver8gen) regarding this.

Comment: I'm impressed by the work done by that blogs author to get this working, but beware. This is **NOT** supported by Microsoft at all. I'd be very careful about doing something like this in a production environment.