# Managing Windows application max CPU and memory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi, resource-management

Good day. I have an RDS server (VMware VM) that we use for data analytics tools. These tools are memory and CPU hogs. I understand that there was a Resource Manager built into Windows 2008 R2. We are running Windows 2012 R2.

I am curious what options are available for managing resources per user that accesses the RDS so that if the server has say 80 GB of memory 16 cores associated to it, that no single user takes up more than 16 GB of memory and 4 cores?

Comment: Try this answer https://serverfault.com/questions/571722/is-there-a-replacement-for-the-removed-windows-system-resource-manager-feature

Comment: Thank you for the article Montonero. I has seen that article already. I realize nothing exists built into Windows Server. I was looking for options on a third party solution.